# NLog not creating logs when used in another project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, logging

I have a class library Project and I am using class `Class1` and using `di` method where I'm printing the log.

```
public class Class1
{
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    public void di()
    {
        var config = new LoggingConfiguration();

        var fileTarget = new FileTarget();
        config.AddTarget("file", fileTarget);

        fileTarget.FileName = "${basedir}/test.txt";
        fileTarget.Layout = "${longdate} ${message}";

        var rule2 = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Debug, fileTarget);
        config.LoggingRules.Add(rule2);
        LogManager.Configuration = config;
        // logger = LogManager.GetLogger("Testing");
        logger.Trace("Testing");
        // add log message
    }
}
```

Now I have another project here I am using classlibrary project reference of method di but when I use di, it doesn't create a log file.

```
Class1 obj = new Class1();
obj.di();
```

Answer (score 0):

There must be some settings in **app.config** file of class library regarding **NLog**. If you copy those settings in **web.config**, then it will start working as per your expectations.